# Не могу получить значение ячейки в столбце 1 и 2. Подскажите правильно написан код?

Tags: javascript

```js
var k = 0;

function add() {
  $('tr').each(function(row) {
    var col1 = $(row).children('td:nth-child(1)').text();
    var col2 = $(row).children('td:nth-child(2)').text();
    if (col1 == 'опоздание более 15мин' && col2 == 'согласовано') {
      console.log(col1, col2);
      return ++k;

    }

  });
}
console.log(add());

$('span.str').text('' + k);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>опоздание более 15мин</td>
    <td>согласовано</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<span class="str"></span>
```

Comment: Вы  вы выбираете что-то из html, но его не показали

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, поправил.

Comment: @Kromster, 1 и 2. Эти цифры обозначают порядок столбцов по факту и все.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так, дело в том что в ф-ция each находит массив элементов (даже если он 1), первый параметр это индекс элемента в массиве, а второй сам элемент, Вы пытались использовать индекс вместо элемента. Также дождитесь загрузки jQuery.

```
<script>
        var k=0; 
    jQuery(function($){

        console.log(add());
        $('span.str').text(''+k);
    });     
    function add(){
        $('table tr').each(function (row, e) {

            var col1 = $(e).children('td:nth-child(1)').text();
            var col2 = $(e).children('td:nth-child(2)').text();
            if (col1 == 'опоздание более 15мин' &&  col2 == 'согласовано') {
                console.log(col1, col2);
                return ++k;
            }
        }); 
    }



    </script>
```

Comment: то что нужно, работает корректно. Спасибо вам.

Answer (score 1):

В функции each должно быть 2 переменных первая - порядковый номер, вторая - сам объект.

```js
var k = 0;

function add() {
  $('tr').each(function(nomer, row) {

    var col1 = $(row).children('td:nth-child(1)').text();
    var col2 = $(row).children('td:nth-child(2)').text();
    if (col1 == 'опоздание более 15мин' && col2 == 'согласовано') {
      console.log(col1, col2);
      return ++k;

    }
  });
}
add();

$('span.str').text('' + k);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>опоздание более 15мин</td>
    <td>согласовано</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<span class="str"></span>
```